# Distributions of differences after sorting and pairing

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sorting

## Question

Suppose we sample $2n$ values $(x_i)_{i=1}^{2n}$ from some distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ (say the $x_i$ are i.i.d. normal).  We then sort the values $x_{\pi(1)}\leq\ldots\leq x_{\pi(2n)}$ and consider the differences $d_k=x_{\pi(n+k)}-x_{\pi(k)}$, $1\leq k\leq n$.

Numerical example ($n=4$):  The sequence 3, 5, 3, 1, 7, 2, 4, 4 gets sorted to 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7 and the differences are $4-1$, $4-2$, $5-3$, $7-3$ or 3, 2, 2, 4.

| input | 3 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sorted | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 7 |

| top half | bottom half | difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 4 |

What are the distributions of the differences $d_k$?  I'm not sure how to approach this without resorting to simulation.  Is there anything like a closed-form solution or expected values or anything worth saying (say for i.i.d. normal $x_i$)?

## Experiments

[Uniform $[0,1]$] Here are 10 experiments superimposed, each the average of 100,000 trials for $n=128$ and $x_i$ uniform on $[0,1]$, i.e. each curve is a simulation of $f(k)=\mathbb{E}(d_k)$.  This agrees with the theoretical result in the next section.

[image]

[$\mathcal{N}(0,1)$] Here are 10 experiments superimposed, each the average of 100,000 trials for $n=128$ and $x_i$ standard normal, i.e. each curve is a simulation of $f(k)=\mathbb{E}(d_k)$.  This is kind of what I expected, a U-shaped curve.

[image]

## Order statistics for the uniform distribution

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) has some information about order statistics for the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  From this we find that the expectation of the differences is constant,
$$
\mathbb{E}(d_k)=\frac{n}{2n+1},
$$
which agrees with the experiment above ($128/257=0.498...$).

Comment: In general, those sorted values $x_{\pi(n)}$ are called “order statistics” and the differences $x_{\pi(n+1)} - x_{\pi(n)}$ between consecutive order statistics are called “spacings”. As your $d_k$ variables are closely related to spacings, searching for some properties of order statistics and spacings of a certain distribution (e.g. uniform or normal) should help.